# Hyperledger Fabric cannot build network from my own CA

Tags: openssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been working with this [IBM tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-build-blockchain-network-with-custom-cryptographic-material-from-your-certificate-authority/index.html?social_post=1149696378&fst=Discover) to be able to deploy my network using my own CA.

I have generated my root and intermediate certificates (with Elliptic Curve Cryptography) using OpenSSL, then I created my self-signed certificates for each identity in the blockchain network (orderers, peers, administrative users, normal users, etc). After that, I populated my crypto-config directory with those certificates.

Finally, I try to create the orderer genesis block with the following command:

```
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

However, I get the following error:

```
2017-12-13 19:25:55.066 CST [configvalues/msp] TemplateGroupMSPWithAdminRolePrincipal -> CRIT 002 Setting up the MSP manager failed, err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

As developer am I able to use my own CA to work with Hyperledger Fabric or I must use the default CA? Do the certificates have to be signed by a well known CA?

Answer (score 0):

The cert that you place in `signcerts` and the cert you place in `admincerts` must be signed / issued by the root / intermediate certs in the `intermediatecerts` directory (as you indicated that you generated an intermediate CA)